# How to solve Uncaught (in promise): Error: Loading chunk 1 failed

Tags: angular

[image]

It is working in local properly while moving the same code in production, the page is loading for a long time.

I used to build: ng build --aot -prod

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Comment: Still we have the issue